# How to apply explode on all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': ['d,e,f', '', np.nan], 'var2': ['1,2', 2, 3]})
```

I am trying to explode all the columns

`df.assign(var1=df['var1'].str.split(',')).explode('var1')`

My current output is below

```
    var1    var2
0   d        1,2
0   e        1,2
0   f        1,2
1              2
2   NaN        3
```

My expected out

```
    var1    var2
0   d        1
0   e        1
0   f        1
0   d        2
0   e        2
0   f        2
1            2
2   NaN      3
```

- I don't know the `column` names it will come difference.
- it will differ everytime and length of column also now its 2 it will increase also
- can we do iloc ?

Comment: shouldn't it be `var2` in your command instead of `var1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split(',') if type(x) == str else x)
for i in range(1, df.shape[1] + 1):
    df = df.explode(df.columns[-i])
```

Output:

```
  var1 var2
0    d    1
0    e    1
0    f    1
0    d    2
0    e    2
0    f    2
1         2
2  NaN    3
```

Another option with successive splitting:

```
for i in range(1, df.shape[1] + 1):
    df[df.columns[-i]] = df[df.columns[-i]].apply(lambda x:
                                                  x.split(',') if type(x) == str else x)
    df = df.explode(df.columns[-i])
```

Comment: why use applymap here

Comment: I have something around 5 columns/26264 rows, I got memory error

Comment: (26264, 6) is my shape

Comment: yess its final shape, but before exploding its (18, 7)

Comment: @Nons I've just tried it with starting shape (20, 10) and result shape (317.700.486, 10) without problems. It took a while and did use quite some memory, but it worked fine.

Comment: is there any alternate way to do?

Comment: @Nons Maybe the upfront splitting is a problem because lists have a higher memory demand. I've added a version with successive splitting, maybe it works better.